# React webpack and babel configuration issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting this error when using webpack:

```
ERROR in ./src/pages/clients/components/ClientProfile.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (18:17)

  16 |     }
  17 | 
> 18 |     handleSubmit = (person) => {
     |                  ^
  19 |         console.log(person);
  20 |     };
  21 |
```

I have following `.babelrc` config

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "stage-3", "react"]
}
```

And here's my `devDependencies` from `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --info",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

And `webpack.config.js` as well

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
                //include: /flexboxgrid/
            }
        ]
    }
```

I can't figure out why it's failing on this syntax

```
handleSubmit = (person) => {
        console.log(person);
    };
```

Does somebody have ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The proposal to add class fields to the language](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) is currently at Stage 2 of the standardization process.

The Babel 'stage' presets work like so:

- `babel-preset-stage-0` only contains what's needed to support Stage 0 features.
- `babel-preset-stage-1` contains what's needed to support Stage 0 *and* 1 features.
- And so on, up to `babel-preset-stage-4`.

Therefore, since you only have `babel-preset-stage-3`, you can't use class fields. To get this to work, you should uninstall that package, install `babel-preset-stage-2`, and then update your configuration files accordingly.

For more details on what exactly the different stages of the TC39 standardization process entail, take a look at the [GitHub](https://github.com/tc39/proposals), and the [process document](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/).

Answer (score 1):

I made following changes in your code and it works fine.

```
{
"babel-core": "^6.6.5",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-es2015-native-modules": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0", //instead of preset-stage-3
}
```

and

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0" //instead of "stage-3"
  ]
```

}

I'll read documentation and come up with the reason until someone else explains it. :)